# CSS ignores class depending on order

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

HTML

```
<div data-countdown="2016-12-10 01:17:26">
   <div class="countdown-text">noch</div>
   <div class="countdown-val">2</div>
   <div class="countdown-text">Tage</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.countdown-val {
    color: red;
}

.countdown-text {
    font-size: 13px;
}
```

Values from `.countdown-val` class are not applied. When I change the order of classes within the css file the same thing happens vice versa. I am using a bootstrap built theme, but I cannot explain this behaviour. Can anybody else please?

Comment: shouldnt happen. can u reproduce this in a codepen

Comment: Unable to replicate your issue. https://jsfiddle.net/2thh7ykm/

Answer (score 0):

you just try this.

```
.countdown-val {
    color: #ff0000;
}
```

otherwise.you can add `!important`

```
.countdown-val {
     color: #ff0000 !important;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS is fine.
Check your closing brackets {} in your code.

In your bootstrap file, make sure your classes aren't nested under another class.

Answer (score 0):

seems like some other css is overriding yours
use

```
.countdown-val {
    color: red !important;
}

.countdown-text {
    font-size: 13px !important;
}
```

or change the class names to some other unique names to be sure that the divs style is not affected by other css

Comment: try to place these line of css at the last of your css file